# ASP.NET MVC and javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

How i can transmission parameters in javascript function from view (asp.net mvc) ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Func(parameter) { 

        }
</script>

<body>
    <% string p = "MessageText"; %>
    <input onclick="Func()"/>
</body>
```

I need transmission string p value to javascript function.

Answer (score 2):

Check this solution -

```
<script>
    @{
        string p = "Message";
    }


    $(function () {
        $("#ClickMe").click(function () {
            var input = '@p';
            alert(input);
        });
    })
</script>

    <input type="button" value="ClickMe" id="ClickMe" />
```

Comment: I get good solution with using: 
<%= Html.Hidden("name", value) %>
and
javascript code:
document.getElementById("name").value;

Comment: @user3240895, you are right, but your question is to how to access a Server side variable in Razor markup, to which we all answered.

Comment: Sorry i answer uncorrectly question, because a i very bad speak english language.

Answer (score 1):

```
<% string p = "MessageText"; %>
<input onclick="Func(<%= Json.Encode(p) %>)" />
```

or if you wanted to subscribe unobtrusively to the click event handler using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#btn').click(function() {
            <% string p = "MessageText"; %>
            func(<%= Json.Encode(p) %>);
        });
    });

    function Func(parameter) { 

    }
</script>

<body>
    <input id="btn" />
</body>
```